# How do you check configuration of existing Qt install?

Tags: c++, qt

The first step to building Qt itself is to run `configure`, setting up the library connections, compiler selection, etc. If the person compiling it was careful and helpful, they saved their config in a convenient, obvious location. If not, however, is there a way for me to check which args were used to `configure` an existing build?

Answer (score 0):

If all you have are the binaries (.DLL/.so files), then "no", there is no easy way. But if you have access to the build configuration then obviously you could dig it out.